# Wordpress menu stopped working after installing SSL certificate

Tags: wordpress, ssl, menu

Please I need help. My wordpress Menu stopped working after installing SSL certificate on my domain only my homepage is working fine. I get this error message every time i click on the menu:

**https’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**

Stepped taking:

1. I have updated my permalinks
2. I installed really simple ssl
3. I have deactivated my plugins one after the other

Yet, the menu still not working. Please anyone who can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a different browser (or even another computer) and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Yes, have used different browsers, cleared browser cache, used VPN and connected to different network. But still the same thing

Comment: Are you able to link us to the site?

Comment: Yes. Here it is: https://pragueairporttransfer.co.uk

Comment: Oh I just noticed something now, I copied one of the page URL and I got this: https://https//pragueairporttransfer.co.uk/service-rates/        The https appeared twice, how can I resolve it please?

Comment: Seems the issue with the Custom link Menu only. Please check and the Menu options.

Comment: Thanks @mark. I solved this issue by getting rid of the existing menu I created via PAGES. I replaced them all by creating a new CUSTOM MENU by inserting the PAGES URL in the custom link.

Comment: Ahh, ya thats a weird thing on how they get stored. I ran across this issue years ago when moving sites around. Glad you figured it out either way.